# Установка цвета в JTextField, который выключен

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

начал использовать JTextField и возникла следующая проблема, в JTextField, который помечен disable() не меняется цвет шрифта.

```
JTextField inputSecStr = new JTextField("Секунд");
        createLabel(inputSecStr);

public static void createLabel(JTextField textField) {
        textField.disable();
        textField.setBorder(null);
        textField.setForeground(Color.decode("#00FF00"));
        textField.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 12));
        textField.setBackground(Color.decode("#000000"));
        textField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    }
```

Для JTextField, к которому я не применяю disable() все работает корректно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `setDisabledTextColor`.